How do I find the problems in my log, separate \include files, when the line number references are unclear?
I am using TexStudio version 4.7.2 (Qt version 6.6.0) on MacOS Monterey 12.7.5 (older Mac)
My document has chapters, which I open as separate .tex files in the TexStudio session. The navigation pane on the left looks like:

I have line numbers turned on.
The problem occurs when I go to the log for fixing an overfull \hbox error. I can't work out where it is. Here are five examples of the warning:

When I click on each of them, TexStudio navigates to here (line in log highlighted, I have also put the red lines over it to show it better):

The line numbers 1308, 1312, 1316, and 1321 don't exist in that chapter, which ends with line 1135. Line 920 is \centering used in a Figure, which fits within the page margins due to me controlling the width for the \includegraphics line.
The .tex file that sets up my packages, has the \include, sets up the glossary and reference files ends at line 225.
I also get errors in the chapters, with correct line numbers. Those I can find and fix.
But how do I find those overfull boxes? The information I have found about line numbers relates to single .tex files, and not a .tex project that has multiple .tex files. I can't interpret the line numbers.

what you show is not the log, but texstudio's not so hellpful summary, if you look in the log file you can always tell which file is open by (path/to/file logging as each file is opened.

you make it very hard to follow as you have obscured the information, but are the overfull boxes not in the file who's name appears on the left G....tex  ? If not that looks like a texstudio bug. But rather than redacting screen shots make a small complete example that you can post here, and show the actual log file as text.

They're not in that .tex file. That's just the start .tex document that calls the packages, the chapters (via \includes), sets up the glossary and reference files. I can't give a MWE because I don't know where the errors are. :(

To give some idea, the PDF that is compiled is currently 260 pages.

The log file is working, I can find the problems now. You're right about the summary being not so useful.
